# how to send <display:column title="Name" property="name"> value to action in struts2

Tags: java, jpa, struts2

I am trying to send property value "name" to action, but I am getting null or empty value at action class. I have also used hidden field as...

```
<s:hidden name="firstName" value="%{firstName}"/>
```

Please find below code:

```
<display:table id="tab" name="testList">
    <display:column title="First Name" property="firstName" style="width:150px;" maxLength="40"/>
</display:table>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @sachin can you please show the jsp code.

Comment: Please edit the question when adding code/information; code in comments is illegible.